# Simple AJAX responseText not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

I have an ASP (Classic) page that uses AJAX and I'm trying to send an sms message and then get a message back saying that the message was sent, The sms message is sent and this works but the page should say that the message has been sent but it doesn't.

THE CODE:

```
   <%
    dim strURLinfo
    strURLinfo = "http://1.1.1.10:9187/sendsms?phone=" & Request.QueryString("phone") & "&password=TESTPASS&text=" & Request.QueryString("text")
'// EXAMPLE URL: http://1.1.1.10:9187/sendsms?phone=4041230207&password=TESTPASS&text=test
    %>
    <html>
    <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" value="NO-CACHE">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //This is to AUTO resend every 20 seconds DISABLED ---> var int=self.setInterval("loadXMLDoc()",20000);
    function loadXMLDoc()
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","<%=strURLinfo%>",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadXMLDoc();">
    <div id="myDiv" style="width: 100%">
    <h3><center>Sending Message....... Please wait....</center></h3>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Resend Message</button>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now if I was to go enter the URL in the address bar of the browser as: ---> strURLinfo (`Example: "http://1.1.1.10:9187/sendsms?phone=4041230207&password=TESTPASS&text=test"`) the page would load and it would send the sms message and it would say: "Message SENT!"
But it will not do it via AJAX/xmlhttp

HTML for the message sent page is:

```
<html>
<body>
Mesage SENT!<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me how to make this work please. I got this example from http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

I don't get any errors, just says: Sending Message...... Please wait... the responseText never changes the div message.

THANKS FOR ANY HELP

Comment: Is there any error messages in your browser?

Comment: Can you show the server-side code for http://1.1.1.10:9187/sendsms ?  Sounds like it's not replying to the XHR request

Comment: @psema4 I wish I had that but I don't it's the address to a android phone and the app is not open source. :(

Comment: Are using the browser's console to look for any errors? Can you track the request by it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work using ASP (classic) using this code:

```
Dim objXML
Function objXML_onreadystatechange()
    If (objXML.readyState = 4) Then
        If (objXML.status = 200) Then
            Response.Write(objXML.responseText)
            Set objXML = Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Function

Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objXML.Open "GET", strURLinfo, false 
    objXML.Send("")
    Response.Write objXML.responseText
```

Making some changes I'm sure one can get this to work in javascript also.